# Compiler error cannot find symbol - Java

Tags: java, imagej

First, I am very new to Java and my programming in general is rusty. So I might have missed something very simple.

The error:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setMethod(java.lang.String)
location: class ij.plugin.Thresholder
        Thresholder.setMethod("Mean");
```

Some code snippets:
This part is third party code. I would like to avoid modifying this as much as possible

```
public class Thresholder implements PlugIn, Measurements, ItemListener {
    private static String staticMethod = methods[0];

    public static void setMethod(String method) {
        staticMethod = method;
    }
}
```

My code (well, some relevant parts)

```
    import ij.plugin.Thresholder;
    public class CASA_ implements PlugInFilter,Measurements  {
    public void run(ImageProcessor ip) {
        track(imp, minSize, maxSize, maxVelocity);
    }

    public void track(ImagePlus imp, float minSize, float maxSize, float maxVelocity) {
        Thresholder.setMethod("Mean");         <-- This is the line the compiler hates
    }
}
```

Why is the compiler looking for a setMethod method with a return of something other than void?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Makoto correctly states, you can't call `Thresholder.setMethod("Mean")` in the class declaration.

In a class implementing `PlugInFilter`, you have to define a `run(ImageProcessor ip)` and a `setup(String arg, ImagePlus imp)` method, so why don't you set the thresholding method during setup of your plugin filter:

```
import ij.IJ;
import ij.ImagePlus;
import ij.measure.Measurements;
import ij.plugin.Thresholder;
import ij.plugin.filter.PlugInFilter;
import ij.process.ImageProcessor;

public class CASA_ implements PlugInFilter,Measurements  {
    // define instance variables:
    ImagePlus imp;

    /**
     * implement interface methods
     */
    public int setup(String arg, ImagePlus imp) {
        this.imp = imp;
        Thresholder.setMethod("Mean");
        IJ.log("Setup done.");
        return DOES_ALL;
    }

    public void run(ImageProcessor ip) {
        // do your processing here
    }
}
```

Have a look at the [ImageJ plugin writing tutorial](http://www.imagingbook.com/fileadmin/goodies/ijtutorial/tutorial171.pdf) or at [Fiji's script editor](http://fiji.sc/Using_the_Script_Editor) and its templates (*Templates > Java > Bare PlugInFilter*) as a starting point.

Comment: You were correct in telling me about not being able to call a method in a class declaration, I actually did not know I can't do that. However, that was not the problem. I still get the same error.

Comment: The code above works for me without errors. I just edited my answer to include all the necessary imports. You can try the code by opening _File > New > Script_ in Fiji, pasting the code, switching to _Language > Java_, and clicking on _Run_.

Comment: This works with the newest version of ImageJ (1.47q). I was trying to run it with 1.46 earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a method in a class declaration block.  You can either do it in the constructor or in another method (that then has to be explicitly called on that class).